# Struct aggregate initialization vs. default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, default-constructor, aggregate-initialization

Given the following initialization of a struct:

```
void f() {
    Struct s {};
    ...
}
```

Will this always do aggregate initialization, or will the `Struct()` constructor be called instead, if it is explicitly defined?

Comment: If you declare a constructor for your class, it is not an aggregate.

Comment: So it isn't possible just by looking at this piece of code to tell if a constructor will be invoked or if all members will be set to zero?

Comment: AFAIK, if `Struct` has a defaulted or deleted default constructor, this will perform an aggregate initialization

Comment: @Danra Without knowing is `Struct` is an aggregate or not you cannot just tell from `Struct s {};` what will happen.